# MySql Statement to Select Based On a Column in Intermediate Table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

In a database, I have a username table and I have jurisdiction table. I also have a intermediate table to assign a user to one or more jurisdictions.

**employee table**

- userID (primary Key)
- firstName
- lastName

records:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
| userID | firstName | lastName |
+--------+-----------+----------+
|      6 | John      | Doe      |
|     11 | lisa      | lopez    | 
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

**jurisdictions table**

- jurId (Primary Key)
- region

records:

```
+-------+--------------+
| jurID | jurisdiction |
+-------+--------------+
|     1 | California   |
|     2 | Texas        |
|     3 | Washington   |
|     4 | South Dakota |
|     5 | Alaska       |
|     6 | Ohio         |
+-------+--------------+
```

**user_jurisdiction**

- userID (Foriegn Key pointing to employees userID)
- jurID  (Foriegn Key pointing to jurisdictions jurID)

records:

```
    +--------+-------+
    | userID | jurID |
    +--------+-------+
    |      6 |     2 |
    |      6 |     3 |
    |     11 |     2 |
    +--------+-------+
```

I've been trying for hours to come up with a sql statement that would select/list all the workers from "Texas". I've been using many altercations of this sql statement but no success:

```
SELECT  jurisdictions.jurisdiction,
        employees.firstName
FROM    jurisdictions,
        employees
        INNER JOIN user_jurisdictions
            ON  user_jurisdictions.jurID = jurisdictions.jurID AND 
                user_jurisdictions.userID = employees.userID
WHERE   jurisdictions.jurisdiction = "Texas";
```

But I have had no success. What sql statement would get a list of employees that are involved from jurisdictions.jurisdiction = "Texas";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing right now is you are producing catersian product from tables: `employees` and `jurisdictions`. The proper syntax of joins is to explicit define the type of join between two tables.

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*
FROM    employees a
        INNER JOIN user_jurisdiction b
            ON a.userID = b.userID
        INNER JOIN jurisdictions c
            ON b.jurID = c.jurID
WHERE   c.jurisdiction = 'Texas'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0944c/1)

OUTPUT of the current query

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════╦══════════════╗
║ USERID ║ FIRSTNAME ║ LASTNAME ║ JURID ║ JURISDICTION ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════════╣
║      6 ║ John      ║ Doe      ║     2 ║ Texas        ║
║     11 ║ lisa      ║ lopez    ║     2 ║ Texas        ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════╩══════════════╝
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks. Is "employees a" the same as "employees AS a"?

Comment: @dhee yes. the `AS` keyword is *optional*.

Comment: Would my intermediate table benefit from a primary key even thought I am not using/need a primary key for it?

Comment: it uses indexes during join. for best performance, add also an index on column `JURISDICTION` since you want to search on this field.

Comment: Do you mean add index column on user_jurisdictions? Because the jurisdiction already has jurID as the index/primary key.

Comment: no, `jurisdictions.jurisdiction`. Here's an example, `ALTER TABLE jurisdictions ADD INDEX (jurisdiction)`

Comment: I think this is better than using `SQL-86 standard` (*like the other answer has demonstrated*) because it is prone to having cartesian result if you forget to add the joining condition on where clause.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27270/discussion-between-d-hee-and-j-w)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
 e.*
FROM 
 jurisdictions j, user_jurisdiction uj, employees e
WHERE
 uj.jurID = j.jurID AND 
 uj.userID = e.userID AND
 j.jurisdiction = 'Texas';
```

Comment: It's an explicit join, equivalent to INNER JOIN syntax